# Does anyone see the error in this simple Ruby function?

Tags: ruby

This function is supposed to take a string and return the characters in reverse order.

```
def reverse(string)

    reversedString = "";

        i = string.length - 1
        while i >= 0
          reversedString = reversedString + string[i]
          i -= 1
        end
    puts reversedString

end
```

however all the tests return false:

```
puts(
  'reverse("abc") == "cba": ' + (reverse("abc") == "cba").to_s
)

puts(
  'reverse("a") == "a": ' + (reverse("a") == "a").to_s
)

puts(
  'reverse("") == "": ' + (reverse("") == "").to_s
)
```

Does anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: Indent your code with two spaces; generally you can omit the parenthesis when using `puts`.

Comment: We don't use variables like `reversedString` in Ruby. Instead we use snake_case, so `reversed_string`. Also, don't end lines with `;`.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use the default String class `reverse` method like this:

```
"Hello World".reverse
"Hello World".reverse!
```

Check Ruby's String class API at https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html

If you want to make your custom method, you could use a map like this:

```
string = String.new
"Hello World".chars.each { | c | string.prepend c }
```

Comment: It appears the question is dealing with creating a custom-reverse method.

Comment: "...use a map..." should be "loop". Don't use "edit" or "update" tags in questions or answers. We can see what's been changed and when if necessary. Instead, incorporate the change in as if it'd been there initially.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your function isn't returning its result, it's printing it. It needs to `return reversedString`.

As a rule of thumb, functions should return their result. Another function should format and print it.

```
def reverse(string)
    reversedString = "";

    i = string.length - 1
    while i >= 0
        reversedString = reversedString + string[i]
        i -= 1
    end

    return reversedString
end
```

Note: This was probably an exercise, but Ruby already has [String#reverse](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-reverse).

---

It's good that you're writing tests, but the way you're writing them it's hard to tell what went wrong. Look into a Ruby testing framework like [MiniTest](http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/).

```
require "minitest/autorun"

class TestReverse < Minitest::Test
    def test_reverse
        assert_equal "cba", reverse("abc")
        assert_equal "a", reverse("a")
        assert_equal "", reverse("")
    end
end
```

That would have told you that your function is returning `nil`.

```
  1) Failure:
TestReverse#test_reverse [test.rb:16]:
Expected: "cba"
  Actual: nil
```

Comment: Worth noting that `return` as a last line is redundant as the last value will be returned regardless.

Comment: @tadman It informs the reader this is a deliberate choice and not a mistake or an artifact. I know that's not normal Ruby style, but we struggled against implicit return in Perl for decades.

Comment: The sooner people come to embrace the idea of implicit return, the better. It avoids a lot of ugly suprises down the road when your method is inadvertently leaking stuff you didn't intend it to. Plus, let's be honest, implicit return was the least of Perl's struggles. I agree that clarity is important, but in this case it's bordering on clutter, which sort of goes against that principle.

Answer (score 2):

To make this more Ruby-like yet avoid using the built-in `String#reverse` method you'd do this:

```
def reverse(string)
  string.chars.reverse.join('')
end
```

Remember that in Ruby the result of the last operation is *automatically* the return value of the method. In your case the last operation is `puts` which always returns `nil`, eating your value. You want to pass it through.

Try to design methods with a simple mandate, that is, this function should focus on doing one job and one job only: reversing a string. Displaying it is beyond that mandate, so that's a job for another method, like perhaps the caller.

To avoid calling any sort of `reverse` method at all:

```
def reverse(string)
  result = ''
  length = string.length

  length.times do |i|
    result << string[length - 1 - i]
  end

  result
end
```

You can often avoid `for` almost completely and `while` frequently if you use things like `times` or ranges `(0..n)` to iterate over.

Answer (score 1):

`puts` prints and returns `nil`, so the whole method returns `nil`. If, for debugging reasons , you want to inspect what your method is returning, use `p` which returns it's argument (reversedString in this case).

```
def reverse(string)

    reversedString = ""
    i = string.length - 1
    while i >= 0
      reversedString = reversedString + string[i]
      i -= 1
    end
    p reversedString  # !!!

end
```

And all 3 tests return true

Answer (score 0):

If I was going to do this, I'd probably take advantage of an array:

```
ary = 'foo bar baz'.chars
reversed_ary = []
ary.size.times do
  reversed_ary << ary.pop
end
reversed_ary.join # => "zab rab oof"
```

`pop` removes the last character from the array and returns it, so basically it's walking backwards through `ary`, nibbling at the end and pushing each character onto the end of `reversed_ary`, effectively reversing the array.

Alternately it could be done using a string:

```
ary = 'foo bar baz'.chars
reversed_str = ''
ary.size.times do
  reversed_str << ary.pop
end
reversed_str # => "zab rab oof"
```

or:

```
reversed_str += ary.pop
```

I just saw that @tadman did a similar thing with the string. His would run more quickly but this is more readable, at least to my eyes.